# join query not Returning any result

Tags: mysql

The following query is returning an empty set even though the unjoined query returns properly. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT  
    `res`.pt,  
    `res`.desc,  
    `res`.length,  
    `res`.date,  
    `res`.practice,  
    `res`.v,  
    `res`.doc,  
    `res`.rappt,  
    `pt`.first,  
    `pt`.last 
FROM  
    `res`  
JOIN  
    `pt` ON  `res`.pt = `pt`.pt 
WHERE  
    `res`.id =  '1' AND  
    `res`.code =  '123'
```

Thanks.

Comment: Post an SQL Fiddle with the exact DB schema you use and the data you use.

Comment: Add More details, eg your data set and something like

Comment: Perhaps there is no data matching your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is valid.

So, the reason is probably: `pt` contains `NULL` values.

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or make your `pt` columns `NOT NULL`. Using an `INNER JOIN` removes all rows that conatin `NULL` from your result set.

Also double check that your `WHERE` condition is truly reachable.

Answer (score -1):

try this it may work. I suspect that using date and desc column without `` caused you problems as they are both part of MySQL reserved words.

```
SELECT  `res`.pt,  `res`.`desc`,  `res`.length,  `res`.`date`,  `res`.practice,  `res`.v,  `res`.doc,  `res`.rappt,  `pt`.first,  `pt`.last FROM  `res`  JOIN  `pt` ON  `res`.pt = `pt`.pt WHERE  `res`.id =  '1' AND  `res`.code =  '123'
```

note that I changed:

```
`res`.desc
```

to

```
`res`.`desc`
```

and

```
`res`.date
```

to

```
`res`.`date`
```

Comment: That's no problem, as long as those columns that use reserved words are selected using qualified names like `table_name.column_that_uses_a_reserved_word`